# Selenium guardar datos de inicio de sesión

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

tengo un script de python que usa Selenium para automatizar la descarga de unos informes, para acceder al sitio del que se van a descargar los informes es necesario iniciar sesión con un email y una contraseña, y una vez introducidos, se pide autenticación de doble factor con un codigo SMS que llega al teléfono, el caso es que si lo haces desde el navegador de forma normal este inicio de sesión se queda guardado en el navegador o algo por el estilo, y ya no te pide más ni el email ni la contraseña, ni tampoco el sms de doble factor(no te lo vuelve a pedir nunca más, aunque lo abras y lo cierres muchas vece), algo así:

---

### **Primer inicio de sesión:**

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Segundo inicio de sesión:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### ----------

Entonces el problema que tengo es que cada vez que ejecuto el script de selenium es como si usara un navegador nuevo, por lo tanto me vuelve a pedir tanto el correo y contraseña como el codigo de sms de la autenticacion de doble factor. He estado indagando por internet y he encontrado esto

```html
# Configurar opciones de Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# Inicializar el controlador de Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

para hacer que el navegador no aparezca el mensaje "un software automatizado de pruebas esta controlando chrome", pero eso no soluciona mi problema.

Comment: Buenas, no queda claro en tu pregunta si el navegador no te pide la info durante la sesión (mientras está abierto) o no te lo vuelve a pedir nunca más, aunque lo abras y lo cierres muchas veces. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y aclarar esto? Si es esta segunda opción, seguramente la información se esté guardando en una cookie. Aquí -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver puedes encontrar información sobre como almacenar y recuperar cookies con python y selenium

Comment: Verifica si te sirven estas respuestas (en inglés): [enlace1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52394408/1545868), [enlace2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74624816/1545868). Si son útiles, puedes escribir una respuesta en base a lo que tuviste que adaptar.

Comment: SI recuerdo bien al guardar la cookie y pasarla en el capabilities, se puede simular estar logeado, espero no equivocarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buen día, igual y ya has encontrado la respuesta si no y para que al menos quede en el archivo para otra persona.

Lo que tines que hacer es pasar las opciones del directorio de trabajo, por default todo se guarda en tmp y sin parámetros se debe de guardar sobre un nombre por defecto que se va a setear cada que ejecutas la aplicación, en mi caso uso linux y por eso la nomenglatura de directorios pero basta con que lo adaptes en caso de usar windows.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/usuario/appData")
```

Dentro de **`/home/usuario/appData`** cuando ejecutes tu aplicación se generará una carpeta llamada default (ya que no le asigno nombre al perfil) y dentro de esta se guarda toda la información que estas utilizando en el navegador, con lo cual, si terminas tu aplicación y la vuelves a ejecutar, está tendrá los datos almacenados de la sesión anterior, ahora con esto deberás de tener también que recurrir al limpiado periódico si no quieres tener problemas futuros con el almancenamíento.